# Can I use environment variables for liquibase commandline properties?

Tags: liquibase

Can I use environment variables for liquibase commandline properties instead of using a properties file outlined [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html?Highlight=liquibase%20properties).
ex.

```
SET LB_classpath=c:\drivers\postgresql-42.2.11.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that as of today (2020/06/08). June 8th 2020.
If you think that this would be a good feature to have please vote on it [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1179)